# Create a linear fade in qt tab

Tags: qt, styling, qtstylesheets

I am trying to create a fade out effect, instead of elide in the QTabBar.

I need to detect if eliding is required and then fade out the text instead of `...`.

I have tried adding a QSS class but it didn't produce the desired outputs.

Documentation and existing code isn't helping either, any help is appreciated.